# Fastest way to draw quads in OpenGL ES?

Tags: opengl, 3d, iphone, android, shaders

I am using OpenGL ES 2.0
I have a bunch a quads to be drawn, would love to be able to have to pass only 4 vertices per quad as if I were using GL_QUADS, but basically I just want to know the best way of drawing a bunch of separate quads.

So far what I've found I could do:

- GL_TRIANGLES(6 vertices per quad)
- Degenerate GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP(6 vertices per quad)

Possibilities I've found:

- GL_TRIANGLE_STRIPS with a special index value that resets quad strip(this would mean 5 indexes per quad, but I don't think this is possible is OpenGL ES 2.0)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just use index buffer and GL_TRIANGLES. In this case you need 4 vertices + 6 indices per quad (6 additional indices may sound large overhead but in reality it is not - once you have constructed your index buffer you don't have to touch it again). See [this page for more information](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vertexarray.html) (search for glDrawElements)

Simple example code:

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {-1, -1, 0, // bottom left corner
                      -1,  1, 0, // top left corner
                       1,  1, 0, // top right corner
                       1, -1, 0}; // bottom right corner

GLubyte indices[] = {0,1,2, // first triangle (bottom left - top left - top right)
                     0,2,3}; // second triangle (bottom left - top right - bottom right)

glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indices);
```

Also, if you are drawing just one quad you need only 4 vertices to draw it with triangle strips ([as shown in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_strip)) but I guess you already knew this.

Comment: The traditional trick for merging multiple triangle strips into a single strip is "degenerate triangles": Repeating the last element of one strip and the first element of the next strip creates 2 triangles with zero area, that thus draw nothing. Consider second quad indices (4, 5, 6, 7). Index buffer for GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP of two quads could be: {0, 1, 2, 3, `3, 4,` 4, 5, 6, 7}. The degenerate triangles are `3,3,4` and `3,4,4`. Is it worth doing this? No, unless your quads tend to come in pairs (or more) with common edges. If 2nd quad is {3, 2, 4, 5} then strip is `{0,1,3,2,5,4}`.

Comment: And to make this clear to anyone who comes along and needs to draw a bunch of quads:  For the sake of performance, **DO NOT** copy the above code, and make a glDrawElements call **ONCE FOR EACH QUAD**. Instead, build up ONE vertices array and ONE indices array that includes **ALL** the quads you want to draw.  Using GL_TRIANGLES, two quads could have indices `{0,1,2, 0,2,3, 4,5,6, 4,6,7}` or equally good is `{0,1,2, 2,3,0, 4,5,6, 6,7,4}`.  Good class to help this is [glText-Android/SpriteBatch](https://github.com/jodem/glText-Android/blob/master/src/com/android/texample/SpriteBatch.java)

Answer (score 7):

Using index buffers isn't *necessarily* faster, as indicated in the Apple docs, ["For best performance, your models should be submitted as a single unindexed triangle strip using glDrawArrays"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3ddrawing/conceptual/opengles_programmingguide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH107-SW1).

So, while a `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` will do it in 4 vertices without needing an index buffer, and you *can* use an index buffer, it's pretty lame to try to "save" repeating *2 vertices*.  For this reason, *I'd suggest you draw 2 separate `GL_TRIANGLES` and repeat the 2 vertices on the diagonal*.

Comment: Um, no. What that doc says is that your models be submitted as a single INDEXED triangle strip. And the very next sentence is, "To avoid specifying data for the same vertex multiple times in the vertex buffer, use a separate index buffer and draw the triangle strip using the glDrawElements function". Which is exactly what you decided was 'lame'.

Comment: Given that the doc paragraph now refers to glDrawElements rather than glDrawArrays, it has probably been re-written since this answer. Nevertheless, the point the doc was making was that, for performance, supply a **single** strip (rather than multiple strips, hence multiple gl calls). In this situation, I believe the difference between using indices or not is **insignificant**; what matters is getting everything into a single vertex array (plus an optional index array), so that you can make a single gl call.

Answer (score 1):

The big gain on desktop is to move the data into GL_STATIC_DRAW VBOs.  Presumably this is true on iPhone's MBX GPU too.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I might add that, at least with triangle lists, one might prefer to use the ordering `{ 0,1,2,0,2,3 }` over the more 'typical' ordering `{ 0,1,2,2,3,0 }` as it puts `0` as the first vertex in both triangles.

Combined with `GL_FIRST_VERTEX_CONVENTION`, this allows for the 0th vertex to dictate flat-shaded attributes for the whole quad, which is somewhat useful in cases where the whole quad can be defined by one property i.e. color.

Answer (score 0):

Using `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` for a quad uses 4 vertices, not 6.

Comment: Yep, but so does `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`, as other answers have already pointed out.

Comment: @Mr. Blah - You have missed the point of the question, which is how to efficiently do a **bunch** of quads. One should not make a gl call for each quad, but rather combine a lot of quads into a single array, that can be drawn with a single gl call. GL_TRIANGLE_FAN won't help with this, hence is rarely useful in high-performance rendering.